# EF 0 to Many code first database setup

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am having trouble setting up my database to properly for 0 to many (not 1 to many). I have `WordModel` objects which represent a given word. Within each are `ICollection<WordModel>` representing the synonyms of that word as a noun, adverb, ect. The database is slowly filled out with queries to an online thesaurus API. The API is only queried when the synonyms of a given word are requested. My WordModel class:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Word { get; set; }
public WordType Traits { get; set; }
public bool SynonymsQueried { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<WordModel> NounSynonyms { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<WordModel> VerbSynonyms { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<WordModel> AdjectiveSynonyms { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<WordModel> AdverbSynonyms { get; set; }
```

I use the `SynonymsQueried` to check if this word has been queried or not. This is so I can populate the synonym collections with `WordModel` objects while keeping track of whether or not those word's themselves have been queried (or else I would query recursively for potentially a very long time). There is no reason for any `WordModel` to have any knowledge of any synonym lists it might be included in, I only want to keep track of its own personal synonyms (which will remain null or empty until specifically queried).

The database that is generated from this model is a single table with a 1 to many relationship. Every `WordModel` has an Id referencing to a *parent* `WordModel` which wont make sense if multiple `WordModel` objects include another `WordModel` in their synonym collection.[image: Screenshot of Database Schema]

I could make the relationship Many-To-Many but I don't know how to force this using Code First. It is also important to note that I have no experience with Model First or Database First EF, I am hoping this is possible with Code First.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want are four many-to-many self-referencing relationships without reverse navigation properties. Please try the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<WordModel>()
      .HasMany(x => x.NounSynonyms).WithMany()
      .Map(x => x.ToTable("WordModelNounSynonym")
          .MapLeftKey("WordModelId").MapRightKey("SynonymId"));
  modelBuilder.Entity<WordModel>()
      .HasMany(x => x.VerbSynonyms).WithMany()
      .Map(x => x.ToTable("WordModelVerbSynonym")
          .MapLeftKey("WordModelId").MapRightKey("SynonymId"));
  modelBuilder.Entity<WordModel>()
      .HasMany(x => x.AdjectiveSynonyms).WithMany()
      .Map(x => x.ToTable("WordModelAdjectiveSynonym")
          .MapLeftKey("WordModelId").MapRightKey("SynonymId"));
  modelBuilder.Entity<WordModel>()
      .HasMany(x => x.AdverbSynonyms).WithMany()
      .Map(x => x.ToTable("WordModelAdverbSynonym")
          .MapLeftKey("WordModelId").MapRightKey("SynonymId"));
}
```